# PGSQL Codeigniter automatically converts column string to lowercase

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am using pgsql and have this query in codeigniter:

```
$this->db->where('SiteCode', $data->site_code)->update('t1add', $t1add_table);
```

Then it outputs this error 'column "sitecode" does not exist. Perhaps you meant t1add.SiteCode.

I have already tried:

```
$sitecode = str_replace(' ', '',"Site Code");
$this->db->where($sitecode, $data->site_code)->update('t1add', $t1add_table);
```

And

```
$this->db->where('t1add.SiteCode', $data->site_code)->update('t1add', $t1add_table);
```

But it still converts to lowercase.
Am i doing it right? or is there a workaround with this?

Comment: check content of `$t1add_table` array

Comment: @Evgeny the error is at where clause